# Save SQL DataSet to Local MDB File

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, oledb

*Context*

My appliction uses an SQL database from which it reads my datatables at start of my application. If the application would fail to connect to the SQL DB, I have a local Ms Access .MDB file. I have a separate thread that checks if the local database is outdated.

I have a DataTable which I obtain from my SQL connection --> Verified and working
I can connect to my Access database locally and read from it --> Verified and working

*Issue/Question*

I'm trying to update my local database by updating it with the DataTable I obtained from my SQL Connection.

```
public static void UpdateLocalDatabase(string strTableName, OleDbConnection MyConnection, DataTable MyTable)
{
    try
    {
        if (CreateDatabaseConnection() != null)
        {
            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + strTableName;
            OleDbDataAdapter MyAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            OleDbCommandBuilder MyCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(MyAdapter);
            MyAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, odcConnection);
            MyAdapter.UpdateCommand = MyCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            MyConn.Open();
            MyAdapter.Update(MyTable);
            MyConn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

If I debug this snippet, all variables are what they should be:

- strTableName = the correct name for my table
- MyConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MyLocation;Persist Security Info=True;JET OLEDB:Database Password=MyPassword;"
- MyTable = is the correct table that is also used further on by my application

This process runs through without an error and without using the catch but it does not touch my database, it just doesn't do a thing.

Am I dropping the ball here or just missing the obvious, I have no idea but I browsed many articles and apart for showing the MyAdapter.Update(), there doesn't seem to be much more to it.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export SQL DataBase to WinForm DataSet and then to MDB Database using DataSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786458/export-sql-database-to-winform-dataset-and-then-to-mdb-database-using-dataset)

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai It is indeed a duplicate - the other question apparently was misleading and confusing so I stripped down that question and made sure to have a clearer question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your backup database have to be in access? because if you used SQL Compact Edition it'd be much easier to copy between the two?

Yes, it would either mean attaching it with your installer or just ensuring that all client machines have it pre-installed, it is free however.

if this is an issue then all you need to do (I think, not done it myself)
would be to go to your installer projects properties, click prerequisites and then tick SQL compact so that it will be installed before your application can be used, iv done this before with other frameworks and it just pops up a box with the install shield asking whether they want to download the necessary software and its just one click then it should be done for them.

Do you need a hand on using the compact database also?

One negative by the way is it does lack some higher end features but shouldn't affect average database work

*EDIT*

if you will be using sql CE you can easily make the databse in VS by clicking data and new data source then following the steps making sure to put sql CE when asked

if it works, you'll end up with an .sdf database

Comment: +1 - good suggestion - thanks for the quick answer Alex, I indeed have gotten the suggestion to do it in the compact framework but would this mean that I would have to include SQL CE in my installer? because currently, Ms Office is installed on all computers running the application, hence me choosing for Access.

Comment: Okay, I've just updated my answer, People have been saying however that it is annoying to have to use a prerequisite especially as it asks the user click more, which as any software developer knows is a bad idea! there's a guide here for doing it manually by attaching the DLLs to your installer 
http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: it is a very basic reading action that I have to perform so the lack of complexity should not be an issue. I'll see what I can find on SQL CE to use it in my app, still wondering why the mdb doesn't work tho.. I'll let you know if I can get it to work or not with SQL CE - many thanks so far

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem at all then! 
Would like to help more but know very little about access
I answered a question a couple days ago about deployable databases with sql if its any use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752295/packaging-a-c-sharp-application-with-a-database/10753431#10753431
good luck!

Comment: Hi Alex, after trying to get this to work now for a few days, it seems to be impossible so I would want to check out the option of doing this with adding DLL's to my app because I wouldn't like to install the compact framework in all the computers in our domain. Any idea on how to get this started? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the meantime I have exported my DB to an sdf file and I can connect to this.. the next step will be to update my local sdf with a dataset I capture from the SQL on the server..

Comment: Same problem.. the date modified on my local sdf changes when I open/close the connection but the actual update does not happen :s

Comment: what exactly isnt working? can you edit your question with a bit of the new code so I can get an idea? 
is it just the date field that isn't working because that may be an issue with the format of sql's dates?

In my first comment there's a link that should point you in the right direction for attaching the DLLs 

prerequisites are essentially just an extra button for clients to press that will install sql CE as part of the normal download if the DLLs look too difficult?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex, the connection to the SQL compact framework and reading the information from it works perfectly with the link you provided so thanks for that :). Now the function I use and where it goes wrong is the DataAdapter.Update(DataTable) command. But the problem is the following. I read my datatable from the SQL on the server and I am trying to make a local backup of that datatable in my SDF. For this I use the Update command but altough it does not return any errors, it does not update my sdf database neither. The code is the same as above, only OleDb will be SqlCe. Thanks

Comment: Okay, well I'm unsure of what the adapter does? is this part of a .net framework or is this a class you've created?

In the worst case scenario I'd suggest using a for each loop and line by line letting your program copy one entry to the other, updating and inserting where necessary

Comment: Looking around the internet, I can't find any real solution other than reading the MDF and then writing that list to the SDF and vice versa 

regarding Your other issue with the client's machine not having sql CE, have you looked at going to the project properties > publish > prerequisites and then selecting sql express? There should already be boxes ticked here as these just adds things to your installer like the .NET framework but checks if they already have it before installing

Comment: Sorry about my slow replies btw, only go on stackoverflow in work and its been a long weekend for everyone in the UK

Comment: No problem Alex - the DataAdapter.Update() is a part of the system.data library. I think that I indeed will have to go over the database line by line to get this to work.

Comment: re-reading your question has made me realize how far off the subject your question is about that we've gone lol, if you need any more help just let me know

Comment: indeed it is :) currently I have i am using an sdf file and I am trying to read line by line from my dataset and use an insert statement. If I can get this to work, I'll post the revised code online and will mark your answer as correct ;-)

Comment: I accepted your answer as you got me on the way of using sdf. I'll reply myself to this question as well with a link to my related question where I added the code snippet. Thanks a lot for all your feedback Alex.

Comment: Thankyou, I've just commented on your code because I can't help but get stuck into your issue lol

Answer (score 0):

I provided a code snippet that fixed the issue on my related question here: [Export SQL DataBase to WinForm DataSet and then to MDB Database using DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786458/export-sql-database-to-winform-dataset-and-then-to-mdb-database-using-dataset)